# How to Set up live radio streaming server

Tags: audio, webserver, media, live-streaming, streaming-radio

I am developing a website for a radio station.

My client wants live streaming of his radio station on the website.

I want to know about required equipment and some guidance to set up live radio streaming server.

Comment: What code have you tried.

Comment: @09stephenb first I want to know about whole set up, then I ll pick programming language according to it.

Comment: This site is for helping people fix there code not giving it to them.